# Como puedo guardar los datos en un IEnumerable del siguiente codigo?

Tags: lista

Lo que ocupo es guardar los datos que me regresa esa consulta en un una lista, para poder ejecutarlo en un WCF llamando esa lista, esto es lo que he tratado:

```
public class ConexionSQL
    {
        public void DatosDB()
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Vi"].ToString()))
            {
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataReader reader;
                cmd.Connection = cnx;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Empleado";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cnx.Open();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t\t{5}\t\t{6}", reader.GetName(0),
                        reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2), reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5), reader.GetName(6));

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                           reader.GetInt32(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3), reader.GetString(4), reader.GetString(5), reader.GetString(6));
                    }
                }
                reader.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

Podrian ayudarme por favor?

Saludos y buenas tardes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo necesitas definir una clase que tenga los siete campos o propoedades que imprimes, e.g.,

```
public class TestObject {
    public int PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
    public string PropertyThree { get; set; }
    public string PropertyFour { get; set; }
    public string PropertyFive { get; set; }
    public string PropertySix { get; set; }
    public string PropertySeven { get; set; }
}
```

Después antes del ciclo while, necesitas definir una lista de esa clase:

```
var objects = new List<TestObject>();
```

Por último en el ciclo whie necesitas agregar la siguiente sentencia:

```
objects.Add(new TestObject()
{
    PropertyOne = reader.GetInt32(0),
    PropertyTwo = reader.GetInt32(1),
    PropertyThree = reader.GetString(2),
    PropertyFour = reader.GetString(3),
    PropertyFive = reader.GetString(4),
    PropertySix = reader.GetString(5),
    PropertySeven = reader.GetString(6)
});
```

De ese modo en cada iteración vas a agregar un objeto y cada objeto corresponde a un registro de tu consulta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Martin, saludos